# Problem when I compile Julia. clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: julia

Recently, I've been trying to compile the Julia project, but I've encountered the following error:

```
'ld: warning: text-based stub file
/Users/jose/Documents/GitHub/julia/src/mach_dyld_atfork.tbd and library file 
/Users/jose/Documents/GitHub/julia/src/mach_dyld_atfork.tbd are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking. 
ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Users/jose/Documents/GitHub/julia/src/mach_dyld_atfork.tbd' for architecture x86_64 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [/Users/jose/Documents/GitHub/julia/usr/lib/libjulia-internal.1.9.dylib]
Error 1 make: *** [julia-src-release] Error 2.
```

This happens with versions `1.9` and `1.8.4` of Julia, but I have no problems compiling version `1.6.4`. I've seen that this could be an issue with Xcode and that updating it may fix the problem, but I don't understand why there's no issue with the earlier version.

Comment: You're going to need to provide some more data to help here. At the very least, your OS and hardware would be good. (I assume mac since Xcode but not sure)

Comment: Yep, It is macOS 10.14, 2,2 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i7